# Tkinter only lets you use 1 button at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

so im making a gui miner for a coin called duinocoin, very new to tkinter.
So i integrated mining into a function, so when you press a button it mines. The problem is when I click mine I cant click anyother buttons because its in that mining loop. How do I fix this?

-Eth guy

Comment: It sounds like you're doing work on the UI thread, which will prevent the UI from working. Ideally, launch a separate process/thread for that work. You'll need a process if you're doing an CPU-intensive work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using `threading`, to create a separate thread from the UI thread:**

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

root = Tk()

def run(): #the loop function
    b1.config(command=Thread(target=run).start) #or b1.config(state=DISABLED)
    while True:
        print('Hey')
        sleep(2) #pause for 2 seconds.

def step(): #the in between function
    print('This is being printed in between the other loop')

b1 = Button(root,text='Loop',command=Thread(target=run).start)
b1.pack() 
b2 = Button(root,text='Separate function',command=step)
b2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Take a look at this example, first run the loop button, then press the next button and you will notice, it gets executed in between the `while` loop. But `sleep()` might still freeze your GUI out.

**Explanation:**
Threading is nothing much, just like a normal thread, imagine cars going through a thread and they got into accident, so the thread might break, just like that, your tkinter runs on one thread and your `while` loop runs with it causing the thread to freeze, but with `threading` you make a new thread for that function with while and hence the thread with tkinter is going smooth, while the thread with `while` loop is frozen, and it doesnt matter for the other thread.

**Alternatively you could also use `after()` for this purpose, like:**

```
from tkinter import *
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

root = Tk()

def run():
    global rep
    print('Hey')
    rep = root.after(2000,run) #run the same function every 2 seconds

def stop():
    root.after_cancel(rep)

def step():
    print('This is being printed in between the other loop')

b1 = Button(root,text='Loop',command=run)
b1.pack()
b2 = Button(root,text='Seperate function',command=step)
b2.pack()
b3 = Button(root,text='Stop loop',command=stop)
b3.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Here when you press the loop button, it will start to loop, when you press the separate button, it prints a function in between the pseudo loop and when you press stop, it stops the loop.

**`after()` method takes two arguments mainly:**

- `ms` - time to be run the function
- `func` - the function to run after the given ms is finished.
- `after_cancel()` takes the variable name of `after()` only.

Hopefully, you understood better, do let me know if you have any doubts or errors.

Cheers

Comment: `command=Thread(target=run).start` will raise exception when the button is clicked more than once.

Comment: @acw1668 i dont see, why someone would want to run the button again, but anyway updated.

Comment: The buttons wont do anything in the threading version since they will be `NoneType Objects`.

Comment: @Atlas435 Good catch, i forgot to update the buttons.